# How can I restrict Spring from injecting beans into a list based on package name?

Tags: spring, kotlin, dependency-injection, filtering

In Spring, I have a `List<ImplementMe>` being injected. My bean have also other parameters≈
All the classes that implement `ImplementMe` are in the same package, but the list may be in a different package and I can also have implementations in different packages.

The question is, can I force Spring to use only a subset of packages when injecting in the `@Bean example`? I know I can set order, but I could not find about filtering.

Possible I could leverage `@Conditional` annotation to do that?

Current implementation with a lot of simplification:

```kotlin
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component


interface ImplementMe

@Component
class One : ImplementMe

@Component
class Two : ImplementMe

@Component
class Three : ImplementMe

class InjectInMe (val listOfImplementation : List<ImplementMe>)

@Configuration
class ConfigExample {
    @Bean
    fun example(listOfImplementation: List<ImplementMe> ) : InjectInMe {
        println(listOfImplementation)
        return InjectInMe(listOfImplementation)
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication(private val applicationContext: ApplicationContext) {
    @Bean
    fun run() = CommandLineRunner {
        println(applicationContext.getBean(InjectInMe::class.java))
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}
```

Using ObjectProvider allows me to filter post injection, see example bellow:

```kotlin
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

interface ImplementMe

@Component
@Qualifier("pkg1")
class One : ImplementMe

@Component
@Qualifier("pkg2")
class Two : ImplementMe

@Component
@Qualifier("pkg2")
class Three : ImplementMe

class InjectInMe (val listOfImplementation : List<ImplementMe>)

@Configuration
class ConfigExample {
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("pkg2")
    fun example1(listOfImplementation: List<ImplementMe> ) : InjectInMe {
        return InjectInMe(listOfImplementation)
    }

    @Bean
    fun example2(listOfImplementation: ObjectProvider<ImplementMe> ) : InjectInMe {
        return InjectInMe(listOfImplementation.filter {
            // simulate filtering by package here
            it.javaClass.name.startsWith("com.example.demo.T")
        })
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication(private val applicationContext: ApplicationContext) {
    @Bean
    fun run() = CommandLineRunner {
        with(applicationContext.getBean("example1") as InjectInMe) { println(listOfImplementation) }
        println()
        with(applicationContext.getBean("example2") as InjectInMe) { println(listOfImplementation) }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}
```

The output:

```
[com.example.demo.One@63b3ee82, com.example.demo.Three@2620e717, com.example.demo.Two@7c8d5312]

[com.example.demo.Three@2620e717, com.example.demo.Two@7c8d5312]
```

Comment: You can use qualifiers so you only get those injected with the specific qualifier. However instead of injecting the list you might want to use an `ObjectProvider< ImplementMe>` which you can then use to obtain the specific instances you need.

Comment: Not sure how @Qualifiers could be used. I tried, and it does not work. The ObjectProvider or filtering list after injecting is a workaround to the question, meaning it solves my problem, but does not answer the question.

Comment: It does answer your question as that is the way to do it, unless you want to rewrite a part of Springs `ApplicationContext` and injection parts. I wonder what you tried, I would expect something like `List<@MyQualifier YourType>` to work.

Comment: I updated the comment above to show that I can use ObjectProvider. Seems good indeed, but I tried Spring's Qualifier and it does not work.

Comment: If you used `@Qualifier` as stated, you haven't tried as I suggest. There is a difference with annotating the type in the list or annotating the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Why not filter the list after injection?

You could filter out instance of classes outside of the required package.

Comment: Of course I can do that, thanks, but that's a workaround solution to my question. It does not answer the question directly.

Comment: I am curious to know the need behind this. No matter what solution you find to filter out some packages, IMO, it is a very bad idea to make your code rely on this information.

Comment: For example, wouldn't sealed interfaces be the correct solution?

Comment: In theory, yes: if I wanted to avoid implementations from outside my module, yes.

However, if my module has an Interface and I need to inject it into two different beans based on the implementations, I would like a way to filter them. Of course, I could create specialized interfaces which makes more meaning to each wrapper component.
There are indeed many ways to solve my problem, but I wanted to know if it is possible to do it using Spring annotations.
Thanks for the feedback.